# Display xml file in the browser using java

Tags: java, xml, jsp

I have an xml file in my computer and i want to display this xml in the browser using java. i have a jsp page and when entering this page i want to display xml file in the browser. 
how can i do this in jsp page with java code. 
for example, my xml path;
C:\xmlexamlpes\sample.xml

how can i display this xml in browser through jsp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting the contentType to `text/xml` and then write out the xml file. Sample code:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/xml" %>
<%@ page import="java.io.*" %>    
<%
//dump out the file
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("path/to/file.xml"));
String line;
while((line = in.readLine())!=null){
    out.print(line);
}
in.close();
%>
```

Alternatively, just redirect your jsp to the xml file or provide a link to it (provided that the file is public).

Comment: thanks for your answer. xml is displayed with your code but there is an error.

XML Parsing Error: XML or text declaration not at start of entity
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
how can i solve this problem. problem is at start of xml(<?xml)

Comment: You've probably got a new line or whitespace before the <?xml starts. You should remove it.

Answer (score 0):

You could read the xml and render it in the jsp. Note that you should escape special characters like `<` and `>` using xml entities or add `<br>` for line breaks (string replace) in order to make the browser display it correctly and not try to interpret it.

Answer (score 0):

You can also Try DOM and SAX Parsers.

[Parsers in Java](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/xml/parsers/package-summary.html)